# Problems uploading jar artifact to hosted maven repository in nexus OSS 3.0.0-03

Tags: maven, nexus

I've just installed OSS 3.0.0-03 on a linux box and it is working well for proxying to Maven central etc. I've created a hosted repository for third party jars but I'm having problems uploading the jar to the repository.

1. Is there any way to do this from the UI like there was in OSS 2.13?
2. I've tried using Maven deploy file goal but it fails with a socket write error:

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-    plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.stream:StreamLib:jar:7.3 from/to nexus (http://kamino:8081/nexus/repository/maven-thirdparty): Software caused connection abort: socket write error

I've checked my firewalls and can see no issues there. The command line I am using is

mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.stream -DartifactId=StreamLib -Dversion=7.3 -DgeneratePom=true -Dpackaging=jar -DrepositoryId=nexus -Durl=http://kamino:8081/nexus/repository/maven-thirdparty -Dfile=StreamLib.jar -e

My maven settings.xml has a 'nexus' server entry for kamino with my admin username and password.

Thanks

Comment: I discovered the problem - the url in -Durl should not have included nexus i.e. -Durl=http://kamino:8081/repository/maven-thirdparty

Answer (score 0):

Nexus Repository 3.0.0-03 does not contain a user interface for component upload. However as you discovered you can use client tools such as the Maven Deploy Plugin.

You can also use simple curl calls. You can see an example at http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/raw.html#_uploading_files_to_hosted_raw_repositories
and similar approaches work for other formats.

A specific upload UI is planned for a future release.